# Suppose $0<a<b$. Prove for all $n\geq 2$, $0< \sqrt[n]a< \sqrt[n]b$.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> Let a and b be real numbers, and suppose $0<a<b$.
>
> Prove for all $n\geq 2$,  $0< \sqrt[n]a< \sqrt[n]b$.

**Proof:** Suppose there exists an $n\geq 2$ such that $0 \geq \sqrt[n]a \text{ or } \sqrt[n]a \geq\sqrt[n]b$.

case $0 \geq \sqrt[n]a $: 
Then $0 \geq a$, which contradicts our assumption that $0<a<b$.

case $\sqrt[n]a \geq\sqrt[n]b$ Then
$a \geq b$, which contradicts our assumption that  $0<a<b$.

In all cases, there is a contradiction with the assumption that $0<a<b$. Therefore, the proposition holds.

---

Is the above proof correct? Can this statement be proven by induction on the natural number?

Comment: The function $x\mapsto \sqrt[n]x$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ using derivative.

Comment: Where's the proof?

Comment: There is no real proof, you could just say: "it's obvious..."

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: This would be a valid proof if you knew that $f(x) = x^n$ was strictly increasing for $x >0$, $n\geq 2$. You can use derivatives, but a more fun approach is writing, for $x<y$, $y=x+c$ and using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this by showing that $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is monotonically increasing when $n\geq 2$.

Let $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1-n}{n}}>0$ when $n\geq 2$, so $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing when $n\geq 2$. Also, $f(x)>0$ when $x>0$. Therefore, for all $n \geq 2, 0<\sqrt[n]{a}<\sqrt[n]{b}$.